# QGIS 3.24.1: Raster Calculator returns error in Model Designer

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

I am trying to calculate a simple substraction between two rasters, after having reprojected one to be in the same CRS as the other. My model looks like this:
[image: Flow chart from QGIS Model Designer. Inputs: swiss_alti3D, ALOS (rasters); Perimeter (polygon vector).]

I get the following in the log:

```
QGIS version: 3.24.1-Tisler
QGIS code revision: 5709b824
Qt version: 5.15.2
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.4.1
GEOS version: 3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0
PROJ version: Rel. 8.2.1, January 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.3.0 (git-version: 9f35b7)
Algorithm started at: 2022-03-24T09:15:00
Algorithm 'raster_difference_MNT' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'alos' : 'C:/Users/Timothy Jeanmonod/Desktop/test/ALPSMLC30_N046E007_DSM.tif', 'perimeter' : 'C:/Users/Timothy Jeanmonod/Desktop/test/Uebungsperimeter.shp', 'swissalti3d' : 'C:/Users/Timothy Jeanmonod/Desktop/test/swissALTI3D_1167_2.tif' }

GDAL command:
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:21781 -r near -of GTiff "C:/Users/Timothy Jeanmonod/Desktop/test/ALPSMLC30_N046E007_DSM.tif" "C:/Users/Timothy Jeanmonod/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ldjLzo/520ef0ebe808460ca6ecad6e5bd63ed0/OUTPUT.tif"
GDAL command output:
Process completed successfully
Creating output file that is 2920P x 4195L. 
Processing C:/Users/Timothy Jeanmonod/Desktop/test/ALPSMLC30_N046E007_DSM.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\RasterCalculator.py", line 144, in processAlgorithm
expression = self.mappedNameToLayer(lyr, expression, layersDict, context)
File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\RasterCalculator.py", line 223, in mappedNameToLayer
layerInContext = expContextAlgInputsScope.variable(varName)
TypeError: unable to convert a C++ 'QPointer<QgsMapLayer>' instance to a Python object

Error encountered while running Raster calculator
Execution failed after 0.67 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'raster_difference_MNT' finished
```

My two rasters don't have the exact same extent and there is an area without overlap, but the Raster Calculator works fine outside of the model. The first one as a 2m resolution, the other one ~30m resolution.
I have tried running the model with my project and data saved on the desktop to ensure short path names. I've tried with other rasters, to no avail.
QGIS user interface is in American English, however my system is in French, should this matter.

Here is the model exported as python:

```
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : raster_difference_MNT
Group : 
With QGIS : 32401
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
import processing


class Raster_difference_mnt(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('alos', 'ALOS', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('perimeter', 'Perimeter', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('swissalti3d', 'Swiss_alti3D', defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(2, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Warp (reproject)
        alg_params = {
            'DATA_TYPE': 0,  # Use Input Layer Data Type
            'EXTRA': '',
            'INPUT': parameters['alos'],
            'MULTITHREADING': False,
            'NODATA': None,
            'OPTIONS': '',
            'RESAMPLING': 0,  # Nearest Neighbour
            'SOURCE_CRS': None,
            'TARGET_CRS': parameters['swissalti3d'],
            'TARGET_EXTENT': None,
            'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS': None,
            'TARGET_RESOLUTION': None,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['WarpReproject'] = processing.run('gdal:warpreproject', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Raster calculator
        alg_params = {
            'CELLSIZE': 0,
            'CRS': 'ProjectCrs',
            'EXPRESSION': '"Swiss_alti3D@1" - "\'Reprojected\' from algorithm \'Warp (reproject)\'@1"',
            'EXTENT': None,
            'LAYERS': parameters['swissalti3d'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['RasterCalculator'] = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'raster_difference_MNT'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'raster_difference_MNT'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Raster_difference_mnt()
```

Did I overlook something?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with raster calculator (works outside of it, crash with similar error message when using it in graphical modeler) also using QGIS 3.24.1. Switched to LTR 3.22 and no more issues. I do think there is an issue with that 3.24.1.

Comment: I've tried with the stable release 3.16.22 and have the same issue but with less details in the log. I'll give 3.22 a try, but I've successfully used the calculator from grass.

Comment: 3.22.7 worked perfectly for me 3.24 most certainly has a problem

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error too while working on QGIS 3.26.1. On QGIS 3.24.2 raster calculator works fine for me.